# What is the name of my sorting algorithm?

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting

I have written a sorting algorithm. What is the name of this algorithm?

```
void sort(int *arr, size_t len) {
    int flag = 1, temp;
    while (flag != 0) {    
        flag = 0;
        for (int i = 0, j = 1; i < len - 1; i++, j++) {
            if (arr[i] > arr[j]) {
                flag = 1;
                temp = arr[i];
                arr[i] = arr[j];
                arr[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you need that outer loop checking if `flag != 0`? Wouldn’t `while (true)` be clearer?

Comment: The `if (flag != 2) break;` is redundant, and should be removed. Set `flag = 0` before the `for` loop, and `flag = 1` inside the `for` loop. That way, the `while` loop will end when no swaps were made.

Comment: @Satyam S This algorithm is called "bad style of programming". At least it can invoke undefined behavior.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow ?

Comment: It's a rather bad variant of bubble sort. It finishes when there are no swaps in a pass, which is good, but it doesn't reduce the size of each pass, which is bad. Also, it fails horribly if `len` is 0.

Comment: @user3386109 made changes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is [bubble sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort): repeatedly loop over an array swapping adjacent elements and stop when nothing is swapped.